# Should i learn double bass with an online teacher?

Tags: teaching, double-bass

I want to learn double bass but  i live in a country that there is no bass teachers at all, so i will have to learn online, is that feasible and effective? because if i want to learn double bass that is my only option.

Comment: If it's your only option, then it's your only option.

Comment: By the way, there are several votes to close this question as opinion-based, but if you don't mind, I've replaced the word "advisable" with "feasible and effective," since I think that's what matters and can be answered more objectively.

Comment: You should be able to determine whether it’s working for you in two to four lessons or so. If it’s not, you stop taking lessons from that person. Even better if you can rent a bass at the beginning. Try it and see if it works for you - we won’t be able to tell you objectively whether it will or not. You’ll have to give it a shot and determine your own answer.

Comment: Related to the votes to close and your edit - I’m on the fence about voting to close. Learning clarinet and classical guitar over zoom has been working great **for me**. So it **can** be effective, but that doesn’t mean it always will be. And I managed to find excellent teachers. So I think every situation is potentially different. Will it work for you? Subjective. Can it work at all? Objectively yes.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Right, thus my edit to make it basically "can it work," which I think doesn't violate the heart of the OP's intent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is absolutely possible to learn effectively via telepresence (Zoom, FaceTime, Skype, etc.). Yes, it's not as efficient or easy as learning in person, but it's much more effective than trying to learn without a teacher.

Often, we get the question "Can I teach myself ___ without a teacher?" and the answer is often "Hm, I don't know, maybe kinda, I guess, but honestly *maybe* not, and it would definitely be really slow and you might learn some bad technique that will limit you." In comparison, the question "can I learn via telepresence" is "Yeah, it might be slower than in person, but if you're committed and the teacher is competent, you absolutely will make reasonable progress."

I'm skeptical that there really are no bass teachers at your disposal at all, though. Maybe none within a distance that lets you have regular weekly lessons, but if there's a major city within a day's travel, there's a strong chance that it has a few music teachers. If it's possible, it would be great to augment telepresence learning with an in-person lesson or two, even if it's just one or two per year.

Also, do you already have an instrument? An acoustic bass is a big object and a big purchase, and I have to imagine that there are places where it's almost as hard to obtain as a teacher.

Comment: I should add, throughout 2020 my daughter took Zoom lessons with a piano teacher in another country. They worked quite well for her—in fact, maybe better just because the teacher was such a good one and perfect fit for her. (Though in person *with that teacher* would still have been even better.)